# Stored procedure, building SQL query gives Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following SQL code

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetMessages]
(
  @dateFrom DATETIME = null,
  @dateTo DATETIME = null,
  @messageType NVARCHAR(100) = null,
  @freeText NVARCHAR(255) = null,
  @freeTextSearch BIT,
  @maxRecords INT = 500
 )
 AS
 DECLARE @sqlstr NVARCHAR(1000)
 SET @sqlstr = N'SELECT TOP @maxRecords ma.*, mp.* 
          FROM MessageData ma 
          LEFT JOIN MessagePages mp 
          ON ma.id=mp.id 
          WHERE 1=1 '

 IF @dateFrom <> NULL AND @dateTo <> NULL
BEGIN
    @sqlstr = @sqlstr + N' AND ma.created BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo'
END

IF @messageType <> NULL
BEGIN
    @sqlstr = @sqlstr + N' ma.msgtype = @messageType'
END

IF @freeTextSearch = '1'
BEGIN
    @sqlstr = @sqlstr + N' CONTAINS(msgdata, @freeText)', 100
END

BEGIN
@sqlstr = @sqlstr + N'ORDER BY ma.id DESC'
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstr, N'@dateFrom DATETIME = null,
                       @dateTo DATETIME = null,
                       @messageType NVARCHAR(100) = null,                   
                       @freeText NVARCHAR(255) = null,
                       @freeTextSearch BIT,
                       @maxRecords INT = 500'
```

However, in all the IF statements where I try to append to the Query it gives me the following:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetMessageV2, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near '@sqlstr'.

I've tried a variety of things but I simply can't figure this one out.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `SET` in *all* `IF` statements, e.g.:

```
IF @messageType <> NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + N' ma.msgtype = @messageType'
END
```

Also, `,100` after the `CONTAINS` is syntactically incorrect. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Many thanks. :) I'll flag it as the answer as soon as the inital waiting period is up. :9

Comment: @JaggenSWE I also think `AND` is missing from second and third `IF`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is in this line

`@sqlstr = @sqlstr + N' CONTAINS(msgdata, @freeText)', 100`

You just have to remove the `,100`

Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly not I'm afraid. It's as if though I'm not allowed to use the @sqlstr after the first SET statement